# jQuery animation if load() returns something different

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
setInterval(function() {
                var prevTopArticle = $("#toparticles table:first").html();
                  $("#toparticles").load("myurloffeed.com/topfeed", function()
                   {
                       alternateBG();
                       var newTopArticle = $("#toparticles table:first").html();
                            if (prevTopArticle!=newTopArticle)
                                {
                                     $("#toparticles table:first").effect("highlight", {color:"#faffc4"}, 2000);
                                }
                  });
                }, 8000);
```

So it sets the current first table item to a variable, loads the toparticles div with the tables off the url, and if they are different it will perform the highlight effect, however it does the highlight effect anyway, completely unsure why it isn't working.

Comment: Try using firebug and console.log to see what is in the variables prevTopArticle and newTopArticle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason one of the articles was outputting a twitter link and the other wasn't, thought the feeds were the same. Figured it out using console.log of the two variables.